# Do authors ever think about the literary devices going into their work?

Tags: terminology

I'm a Judy Blume fan, and I found [this article](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/Fudge?from=Literature.FudgeAMania) on TV Tropes. I noticed that they listed a lot of common themes and patterns.

Are authors aware of the literary devices they use when they first write their stories, or is it usually done subconsciously, leaving it up to analysts to interpret them?

Comment: Welcome to Literature! I'm not sure, but I think this question may be too broad to be reasonably answered. Some authors will think about literary devices while writing, some won't. Usually *some* literary devices might be consciously planned while others are unintentional or subconscious. But there's such a wide range here, so many different authors and works to be considered, that I'm not sure your question can be answered in the scope of a single post.